# How to update $auth.user properties in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

When I want to update `$auth.user.balance`:

```
methods:{
   test(){
      this.$auth.user.balance = 10;
   }
}
```

But it returns error:

```
Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

How can I update these vuex properties in Nuxtjs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nuxt provides `$auth.setUser()` method to set user.

Use `$auth.setUser()` like so:

```js
const userToUpdate = {...this.$auth.user}
userToUpdate.balance = 10;
this.$auth.setUser(userToUpdate)
```

Data updating in store always should be immutable.

So create a new reference of object before passing it to `setUser` to avoid the reactivity issue.

Comment: In my case, when using this.$auth.user in a computed variable it was not updating the DOM, i've needed to use this.$auth.user directly.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using Vuex you should only mutate your state throught your mutations, in your Vuex you should create a mutation like this :

```
  setBalance(state, payload) {
    auth.user.balance = payload;
  },
```

and in your component you need to map your new mutation in your `methods`,

```
 ...mapMutations('auth', ['setBalance']),
```

don't forget to import the mapMutations from vuex

```
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex';
```

and in your component when you want to set a new value to balance you call

```
 test(){
         let newValue = 10;
         this.setBalance(newValue);
       }
```

You can learn more about mutations in Vuex store [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) in Vuex documentation